# Add additional options to Django form select widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form which I use to construct a queryeset filter. The form pulls in the project status options from the database. However, I wanted to add additional options, for example "All live promotions" ... so the select box would then look something like:

- All Promotions *
- All Live Promotions *
- Draft
- Submitted
- Accepted
- Reported
- Checked
- All Completed Promotions *
- Closed
- Canceled

Here the '*' are the ones I'd want to add and the others come from the database.

Is this possible?

```
class PromotionListFilterForm(forms.Form):
    promotion_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Promotion Type", queryset=models.PromotionType.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'selector'}))
    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Status", queryset=models.WorkflowStatus.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'selector'})) 
    ...
    retailer = forms.CharField(label="Retailer",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textbox'}))
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You won't be able to use a ModelChoiceField for that. You'll need to revert to a standard ChoiceField, and create the options list manually in the form's `__init__` method. Something like:

```
class PromotionListFilterForm(forms.Form):
    promotion_type = forms.ChoiceField(label="Promotion Type", choices=(),
                                       widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'selector'}))
    ....

    EXTRA_CHOICES = [
       ('AP', 'All Promotions'),
       ('LP', 'Live Promotions'),
       ('CP', 'Completed Promotions'),
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PromotionListFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = [(pt.id, unicode(pt)) for pt in PromotionType.objects.all()]
        choices.extend(EXTRA_CHOICES)
        self.fields['promotion_type'].choices = choices
```

You'll also need to do something clever in the form's `clean()` method to catch those extra options and deal with them appropriately.