# django admin missing records

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a `company_images` table that **belongs** to `country_master` except when country_id is **0**. If country_id is 0 i am assuming it's 'all locations'. But since 0 doesn't exist in country_master. It returns no result for those entry in company_images listing. How do i fix it.

Forgive me if this is a simple thing coz i am new to python/django.

Model.py

```
class CountryMaster(models.Model):
    country_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "country_master"

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.country_name is None:
            return "None"
        else:
            return self.country_name


class CompanyImage(models.Model):
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='company', max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey(CountryMaster)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = "company_images"

def __unicode__(self):
    return "None"
```

I have tried this and mentioning this in admin.py as a display filed

```
def country_name(self):
    if self.country_id is 0:
        return "ALL"
    else:
        return self.country
country_name.short_description = 'Country'
```

Comment: One work around is, make `country` nullable (`null=True, blank=True`) and if blank, assume __all__ locations. That, in my opinion would be cleaner. Another option, Have a special value - `country_master.name='all'`, and assign the __all__ case to that object

Comment: this works for me. plz put this up as the answer. so that i can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: also could you explain option b in details. i didn't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work around is, make `country` field nullable (`null=True, blank=True`) and if empty, assume `all` locations. That, in my opinion would be cleaner.

Another approach would be to create a `CountryMaster` object (as a fixture) for the `all` option - In other words, a fixture that loads to the database, a `CountryMaster` object with `name=all`. So, whenever the user selects `all`, you can assign the reference to this object.

Comment: i would like to know how can i add extra entries to dropdown in the add form.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700445/add-additional-options-to-django-form-select-widget)